# Wrong WParam value in IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage

Tags: c#, winforms, imessagefilter

I am currently in the process to implement a application-wide keyboard hook for one of my applications.
This is done by using a `IMessageFilter` implementation overriding the `PreFilterMessage` method and adding that `IMessageFilter` to my main form.
As far as i was able to test, most of the number and letter keys work without any problem, but when it comes to, let's say, `Keys.Left` (code 37), the `WParam` of the `Message` contains a, as it seems, wrong value (code 39).
And yes, i already did a bit-AND with `Keys.KeyCode` (which is 65535 btw. which means it wouldn't even matter).

If anyone has an idea or a hint why it works for letter/number keys but not for `Keys.Left` I would highly appreciate that.

Code:

```
public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
{
    if(m.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        _keyTable[(Keys)m.WParam & Keys.KeyCode] = true;
    }

    if(m.Msg == WM_KEYUP)
    {
        _keyTable[(Keys)m.WParam & Keys.KeyCode] = false;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: It is never wrong.  Key code 39 is Keys.Right, never very far away from Keys.Left.  Only sane advice is to stop using the keyboard upside-down ;)

Comment: @HansPassant holy freaking hell, how dumb can one be (me, not you, obviously)... haven't used the kbd upside-down but my mind was just mixing left and right again (as most of the time)... and i am sitting here hour after hour and just don't get it right (or left, for that matter). Thx xD

Answer (score 1):

I Faced the same problem in Numpad Keys.

I Did the following:

VB.NET:

```
    Dim KeyPressed As String
            Select Case CType(m.WParam.ToInt32(), Keys)
                Case Keys.NumPad1 : KeyPressed = "1"
                Case Keys.NumPad2 : KeyPressed = "2"
                Case Keys.NumPad3 : KeyPressed = "3"
                Case Keys.NumPad4 : KeyPressed = "4"
                Case Keys.NumPad5 : KeyPressed = "5"
                Case Keys.NumPad6 : KeyPressed = "6"
                Case Keys.NumPad7 : KeyPressed = "7"
                Case Keys.NumPad8 : KeyPressed = "8"
                Case Keys.NumPad9 : KeyPressed = "9"
                Case Keys.NumPad0 : KeyPressed = "0"
                Case Else : KeyPressed = Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(m.WParam)
            End Select
```